# Phantom JS Error with youtube video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

Phantom JS Version: 1.9.1
Poltergeist Version: 1.3.0

Starting today youtube embedded videos now give a poltergeist error when running javascript tests.  My youtube code is just the default embed youtube code.  Here's a example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AW9Z3cGOlGM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the errors I get just from visiting that page while enabling javascript is:

```
 Failure/Error: page.find(".container.registrations.false.government")["style"].should have_content("test.jpg")
 Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
   One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

   TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.dataset')
       at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl6vSff7.js:97
       at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl6vSff7.js:88 in vg
       at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl6vSff7.js:85
       at http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl6vSff7.js:98
```

Also in some tests poltergeist just dies..

```
 Failure/Error: visit root_path
 Capybara::Poltergeist::DeadClient:
   PhantomJS client died while processing {"name":"visit","args":["http://subdomain13.lvh.me:3003/"]}
```

Additionally it does not ignore these errors when doing:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_without_js do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :js_errors => false)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_without_js
```

Comment: Not a great solution, but we ended up having to make sure that our embedded videos only showed up due to a user interaction to prevent phantom from attempting to run the ytimg code. This made our tests pass (and let us deploy).

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm using `<iframe youtube stuff><% unless Rails.env.test? %>` which also makes our tests pass.  hopefully there becomes a better solution though

Comment: This randomly started happening in my tests just now, but doesn't happen in the browser. Can't work out why. I'm specifically testing YouTube embeds, so can't ignore it. :-/

Comment: Looks like a JS error in YouTube's embedding fallback code: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/youtube/chrome/2Cu87teAGYE

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the embed JS handling browsers that don't support flash or html5 video:

Discussion at https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/youtube/2Cu87teAGYE/discussion

Bug report at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5883